# azure-ad-b2c userinfo_endpoint missing

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using the [Android sample app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-appauth) to do some testing of Azure AD B2C and when I authenticate I am getting and ID token, refresh token and Auth token. However, I am not getting userinfo_endpoint returned.  As I understand it, this is what enables to view profile button in the app and allows me to retrieve additional profile information.

I'm not sure if I have configured something wrong or if I need to modify the code. The sample code uses the AAD v2 endpoints and I read somewhere that the v2 endpoints do not return userinfo_endpoint but I wasn't sure if that was old information.

How can I get userinfo_endpoint returned?

Answer (score 2):

**At this time, Azure AD B2C does not support the UserInfo endpoint.**

I would recommend adding an entry in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c) with some additional details regarding what you are looking to achieve with the userinfo endpoint.